# How to declare a Numberpicker inside a Tabhost inside a Dialog?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, dialog, android-tabhost

I want to use a `NumberPicker` inside a `Tabhost`which is accessible through a `Dialog`. But How to define the `NumberPicker`? At the moment I'm doing this:

```
NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) d.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
```

But this is not working. I get a NullPointerException in the line below (see code below).

Any advice? or How to do it right?

```
    String[] array = {"1","2","3"};

    public void dialog(){
    final Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.setTitle("Dialog");
    d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    d.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) d.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);

    tabHost.setup(getLocalActivityManager());
    tabHost.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Favs");
    TabHost.TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("All");

    tab1.setIndicator("Favs");
    tab1.setContent(R.id.tab1act);

    tab2.setIndicator("All");
    tab2.setContent(R.id.tab2act);

    tabHost.addTab(tab1);
    tabHost.addTab(tab2);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) d.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
    np.setMaxValue(array.length);   //NullPointerException here
    np.setMinValue(1);
    np.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
    np.setOnValueChangedListener(this);
    np.setDisplayedValues(array);
    np.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);

    d.show();
}
```

**Logcat:**

```
1-30 17:18:27.579  32038-32038/com.app.main E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.app.main.Main.dialog(Main.java:283)
        at com.app.main.Main$1.onClick(Main.java:142)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Dialog.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TabHost
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/tab1act"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                layout="@layout/tab1act" >
            </include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/tab2act"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                layout="@layout/tab1act" >
            </include>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**Tab1act.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Tab2act.xml:**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you init your **array**?

Comment: yes, let me just add that..

Comment: Please post the dialog.xml file, maybe there is no *numberPicker* there, so d.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker) return null

Comment: `dialog.xml` has no `numberpicker` but it includes to other `.xml` Files which have a numberpicker

Comment: Try this: View tab = d.findViewById(R.id.tab1act); NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) tab.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);and see if tab is null or np. Notice that you are including the same layout (tab1act.xml) twice (you call the same xml file).